# axis lines (spines) of axis offset, and extents to fit last ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

Consider the image below. There are two properties I would like to replicate with `PGFplots`

1. Some spines (i.e. axis lines) should be removed (top and right)
2. The spines are pushed outward such that the tick lines do not enter the plot area
3. The spines stop at the the end ticks

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[clip limits=true, enlarge x limits=-1, enlarge y limits=-1]
        \addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0] {
            1
            2
            3
            2
            1
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done exactly with what you would "say", i.e. "shift the axis lines by the length of the ticks".

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines*=left,
        major tick length=10pt,      % <-- for debugging only
        axis line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}},
    ]
        \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Great! Can we make the y-axis line go from -1 to 1 instead of passing it, but doing so without changing the y limits?

Comment: Yes, add `enlarge y limits=false` to the `axis` options.

Answer (score 0):

Just to fully complete the answer:

`axis x line*=bottom, axis y line*=left` removes the upper x axis and the right y axis.

@Stefan Pinnow seemed to have found out what you mean with "spine offset is designed such that the ticks just touch the plot area" [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622159/224762)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            clip limits=true, 
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=left,ymax=3,xmax=4,xmin=-0.1,ymin=0.9,
            axis line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}}]
            \addplot table[header=false,x expr=\coordindex, y index=0] {
                1
                2
                3
                2
                1
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite there as the spines should be outside as well so that the ticks are facing inward. If the xticks were manually set to 1,3, would the spines stop there?

Comment: What is a spine in this context? I do not understand this request.

Comment: The spine is the axis line

Comment: Note I rolled back your edit. My preference is to call the axis lines spines. https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo.html. Notice how the tick length and spine offset is designed such that the ticks just touch the plot area.

Comment: As you wish, I just nowhere found that spine translates to x or y axis.

Comment: Is "spine" the same word as in "backbone, spinal column, or vertebral column"? Or maybe there is an alternative meaning? Anyway I also have never heard about it in this context and the question was difficult to understand.